# how to pass variables between view controllers without a segue in swift

Tags: swift, variables, view, controller

How can I pass variables between view controllers without a segue or the navigation bar in Swift? I've tried defining the variable outside of the class, but the variables are modified so the updates aren't shown when they are accessed in another view controller. I have 5 view controllers, one or two new variables are created on each. My goal is to pass those variables down the line to the last view controller, where all the variables are displayed on one view controller.

Here is an example of some code:

```
class ViewController_name: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    //MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var field_first: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var field_last: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.field_first.delegate = self
        self.field_last.delegate = self
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: Actions

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { //function tests for pressing return in a text field
        self.view.endEditing(true) //closes the keyboard
        return true
    }
    @IBAction func button_name(_ sender: UIButton) { //tests for button click
        let input_name_first:String = field_first.text! //sets the variable input to the first name text field
        let input_name_last:String = field_last.text! //sets the variable input to the last name text field
        print("\(input_name_first) \(input_name_last)") //prints the full name to console
    }
}
```

I can't do this through segues because the sequence of view controllers looks like this:

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5

and I need to get data from 1 to 5.

Code from View Controller 1 to send two variables to View Controller 2.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let name_pass_first = segue.destination as! ViewController_complete
        if let text = field_first.text  {
            name_pass_first.text = text
        }
        let name_pass_last = segue.destination as! ViewController_complete
        if let text1 = field_last.text {
            name_pass_last.text1 = text1
        }
    }
```

Code from View Controller 2 to receive the variables from View Controller  1:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
if let received_pass_first_name = text {
    print(received_pass_first_name)
}
if let received_pass_last_name = text1 {
    print(received_pass_last_name)
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't use Core Data or Realm for this? Another (not so good) option is UserDefaults, or to save them in another DataManager which will be used by the last ViewController to show your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't do this through segues because the sequence of view controllers looks like this: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 and I need to get data from 1 to 5

To say "can't" is just silly. Of course you can. You just keep passing and accumulating the information so that everything needed gets to 5. You just mean you don't *want* to, either because you think it's ugly or because you don't want to take the time to implement it.

But why not? Why not pass, say, a single custom object with all the needed properties that gets populated more and more, and is modified as needed, as it moves down the line until it reaches 5?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches you can take for this:

1. The most obvious one (and the ugliest) one is to simply pass down the values as properties from one controller to the next.
2. A better approach would be to access the values from a data store like CoreData or if the values are small, then UserDefaults. By using this approach, you could access the property values of any view controller that is 'before' the current one – in the stack.